# jQuery ui slider dynamical inline styles on progress

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, backbone.js

I have a jQuery slider in backbone view. The view updates the position of the slider dynamically.

I would like add inline style to the div.ui-slider-range tied to the value of slider.

A the moment I have a view method called from the sliders change event callback. This does not seem to attach the style at all. I get no errors and I have verified that the view method is called when the value is changed.

I have noticed that the div.ui-slider-range has `width` property applied to it inline by jquery ui. I am guessing this is what is giving me problems. Anyway I can get jquery ui to add inline styles for me?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: 
It seems to be a problem with how I am describing the linear-gradient prop.
If I set it to linear-gradient(left, black, white) it works as intended.Any thoughts?

```
render: ()=>
  @$el.slider
    range: 'min'
    min: 0
    max: 100
    value: 0
    animate: true
    step: 0.01
    change: (e, ui) =>
      @updateStyle ui.value
  @uiRange = @$el.find('.ui-slider-range')

updateStyle: (width) ->
  @uiRange.css 'backgound', "linear-gradient(left, #6641cd, #6641cd #{width}%, #15b2e7)"
```

Comment: show your code please?

Answer (score -1):

Alright, turns out this is an issue with jQuery, maybe just something that needs better documentation

The issue lies with jQuery adding the linear-gradient prop. Since linear-gradient prop needs a prefix depending on the system you need to make sure to add the correct one. If you are developing on Chrome you need to add -webkit- prefix or jQuery won't add the property. If you are Firefox, you need the -moz- prefix. If you don't have the correct prefix on the system, jQuery just ignores that css property.

Now the issue I am having is trying to add all the background prefix props. It seems though that jquery will only add the last property, and if the last property is not the correct prefix, that it will ignore all of them. Or more likely it is adding each prop individually, since they are all background props, each one overwrites the last.